# How can I create a directory using crontab and after five minutes create a txt file inside that directory?

Tags: linux, centos, cron

Basically I want to create a directory at some fixed time and after exactly five minutes, I want to create a text file in that directory.

I tried this code but it didn't work

```
6 13 * * * /usr/bin/mkdir /qwerty /usr/bin/touch file1
```

Comment: You should use `at` instead of cron for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the command you asked cron to run:

```
/usr/bin/mkdir /qwerty /usr/bin/touch file1
```

This calls `mkdir` with tree parameters: `/qwerty`, `/usr/bin/touch`,
and `file1`. So, `mkdir` will attempt to create those as directories.
You probably meant to run those as two separate commands:

```
 6 13 * * * /usr/bin/mkdir /qwerty
11 13 * * * /usr/bin/touch /qwerty/file1
```

Another style would do this as a one-liner:

```
6 13 * * * /usr/bin/mkdir /qwerty && sleep 5m && /usr/bin/touch /qwerty/file1
```

Note that using cron for one-off jobs is strange; as mentioned in a
comment to your question, an at job would make more sense.

Also, this will still fail unless the user is allowed to create
directories under `/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "mkdir test && sleep 300 && touch test/file" | at 06:13
```

This will schedule the echoed command to run at 06:13.  If 06:13 has already passed, it will be run at that time tomorrow.

Any output from the job will bu mailed to you.

The the `at` manual for the different ways you may specify the time.